# UITextField inside UIAlertView cannot set cursor

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uialertview

Here is the code I have:

```
    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Confirm Address" message:@"Please confirm your address:" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Confirm" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    UITextField * alertTextField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
    alertTextField.text = @"1234 ABC Street";
    [alertTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    UITextPosition *beginning = [alertTextField beginningOfDocument];
    [alertTextField setSelectedTextRange: [alertTextField
                                   textRangeFromPosition:beginning
                                   toPosition:beginning]];

    [alert show];
```

The cursor does not get set to the beginning of the textfield. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Implement the `UITextFieldDelegate` on your Controller, and move your `setSelectedTextRange` code to the `textFieldDidBeginEditing` delegate callback:

```
UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Confirm Address" message:@"Please confirm your address:" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Confirm" otherButtonTitles:nil];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
UITextField * alertTextField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
alertTextField.text = @"1234 ABC Street";
[alertTextField becomeFirstResponder];

// Your UITextFieldDelegate implementer here
[alertTextField setDelegate:self];

[alert show];

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    UITextPosition *beginning = [textField beginningOfDocument];
    [textField setSelectedTextRange:[textField textRangeFromPosition:beginning
                                                          toPosition:beginning]];
}
```

It is important you specify in your header file, or class extension that you implement `<UITextFieldDelegate>` and set the delegate as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Set delegate of alertTextField to current view controller, and perform setting range in textFields delegate method.

```
UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Confirm Address" message:@"Please confirm your address:" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Confirm" otherButtonTitles:nil];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
UITextField *alertTextField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
alertTextField.text = @"1234 ABC Street";
alertTextField.delegate = self;
[alertTextField becomeFirstResponder];
[alert show];
```

TextField delegate

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    UITextPosition *beginning = [textField beginningOfDocument];
    [textField setSelectedTextRange:[textField
                                     textRangeFromPosition:beginning
                                     toPosition:beginning]];
```